# setTextViewText not updating widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget

Shown below is a simplified version of my class.  I am having trouble in the onReceive method which isn't updating the widget TextView.  It shows the correct information in the logcat which is outputted on the line before the setTextViewText.  I'm not sure whats wrong and have been pulling my hair out (and I'm already balding).

```
public class SnowWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static List<Article> mymtns = new ArrayList<Article>();
public static RemoteViews remoteViews;
public static ComponentName thisWidget;

public static String amount = "";
public static String mtn_name = "";
public static String desc = "";
public static String condition = "";
public static String[] type;

public static int index = 0;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, 
  int[] appWidgetIds) 
{

    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

    thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, SnowWidget.class);

    // This one works fine
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.snowwidget,  mtn_name+ "\n"+ amount+"\"\n"+ condition);

    /* Make the buttons work */

Intent next = new Intent(context, SnowWidget.class);
next.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);

PendingIntent nextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, next, 0);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.nextMtn, nextPendingIntent);

/* END - Make the buttons work */

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // check, if our Action was called
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {
        if(mymtns.size() > 0)
        {

            // This show up correctly in logcat
            Log.d("onReceive", "New Info => "+ mtn_name+ "\n"+ amount+"\"\n"+ condition);
            // This never updates my widget
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.snowwidget,  mtn_name+ "\n"+ amount+"\"\n"+ condition);

        }
    }

    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found the answer.  After calling the `remoteViews.setTextViewText` you need to update the widget with a call to `updateAppWidget`.  The code I added is shown below.

```
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this ! It is difficult to describe how much of a headache this problem has caused me.

Comment: I have this code and it's still not working.. although it was previously. I have no idea what happened.

Comment: Where are you adding those few lines of code? I can't seem to get my widget working.

Comment: I was passing wrong flag for configure activity that did not update the widgetId:
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)
instead of:
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I had strange behaviors with FLAG_ONE_SHOT, and when I set flag to 0 it did not refresh anymore.