# setImageViewResource doesn't work if initialized inside an external function

Tags: android, widget, imageview

I'm building a homescreen widget and my goal is to set an image on the ImageView within this widget and I use `setImageViewResource()` for this. And it works perfectly - *means that the target image `R.id.user_button` changes its image resource to `R.drawable.activity_notification` after `onStart()` was executed* - if I use it like this:

```
public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        ... //Some code which is not really important
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.user_button, R.drawable.activity_notification);
    }
}
```

The problem is I have to put `setImageViewResource()` inside an **external function** and when try to build something like the code below it refuses to work - *means that image resource of the target image `R.id.user_button` remains unchanged after `onStart()` is executed*.

```
public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        ... //Some code which is not really important
        changeImagePicture();
    }
    public void changeImagePicture() {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.user_button, R.drawable.activity_notification);
    }
}
```

I guess I'm a noob and I miss something really simple and very important here. Can you please point at my misstake so I can get my code to work at last ;)
Merci beaucoup!

Comment: You say that you change it in an external class, but you are showing a method (changeImagePicture) in your UpdateWidgetService class.  Is it this method or is it an external class? Please also explain exactly what happens.  What does "refuses to work" mean?

Comment: @Simon You're absolutely right I just messed with this _classes / functions_ definitions. I'm trying to get ImageResource changed using `public void changedImagePicture()` declared outside the 'public void onStart()' which is not working right now. I've updated my question and _highlighted what was supposed to happen and what actually happens_ with italics. Please check. If you need more clarification on this please let me know.

Comment: OK, does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433464/settextviewtext-not-updating-widget

Comment: @Simon no actually it doesn't. I try to set image suing this WidgetUpdate trick and get the same result - picture remain unchanged. I've debugged the code several times and still nothing. Any thought?

Comment: @Simon I've tried once again with your `updateAppWidget` trick and it finally worked! Can you please issue your comment as an answer to this question so I can  vote for it? ))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the updateAppWidget method of the AppWidgetManager class:

```
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

Good luck....

Comment: This helps, found that I commented out this line. Hoping there can be a warning for someone forgot to add this line.