# dataSnapshot retrieves last message but having difficulty displaying it on widget......?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, widget

Finishing of a chat app and have researched lots of questions here (found 1 which put me on track [setTextViewText not updating widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433464/settextviewtext-not-updating-widget))
As you'll see from my code I have followed that question however, Widget is not updating with message. I have debugged and can confirm that last message has been retrieved.

my code:

```
public class ProTalkWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final String ACTION_BROADCASTWIIDGET = "ACTION_BROADCASTWIIDGET";
    public static final String PROTALK_APPWIDGET_UPDATE = "PROTALK_APPWIDGET_UPDATE";

    private final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    public static final String USER_ID = "userId";
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String msgReceiverId;

    private void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                 final int appWidgetId) {

        //Construct the RemoteViews object
        final RemoteViews views;
        views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.pro_talk_widget);




        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, ChatRoomActivity.class);
        PendingIntent mainPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE, mainIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_layout, mainPendingIntent);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProTalkWidget.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_BROADCASTWIIDGET);

        context.sendBroadcast(intent);

        appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);



        if(PROTALK_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())){

            Log.i("onReceive", "getting onReceived!");


            handleMsg(intent, context);


        }
        }


    private void handleMsg(Intent intent, final Context ctx){

        msgReceiverId = intent.getStringExtra("receiverId");


        if(msgReceiverId!=null) {
            final RemoteViews views;
            views = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.pro_talk_widget);

            String my_Id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


            DatabaseReference msgRef = rootRef.child("Messages").child(my_Id).child(msgReceiverId);
            Query msgQuery = msgRef.limitToLast(1);

            msgQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if(views != null) {

                        Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                        String msg = messages.getMessage();

                        Log.i("Views", "views");

                        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_message, msg);

                    }else{
                        Log.i("Views", "not working");
                    }
                    }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}
```

Any help or resources or bits of advice greatly appreciated and welcome.

Thanks

[Appwidget with no message being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDi7b.png)

plus in the logs I'm not getting any error jus the logs of views which I guess represent all the messages loaded(unsure I'm a newbie!).

Thanks again!

Messages

```
public class Messages {

    private String message;
    private String from;
    private String type;
    private long time;
    private boolean seen;

    public Messages(){}

    public Messages(String message,String from, String type, long time, boolean seen) {
        this.message = message;
        this.from = from;
        this.type = type;
        this.time = time;
        this.seen = seen;
    }



    public String getMessage() {
        return message;

    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public boolean isSeen() {
        return seen;
    }

    public void setSeen(boolean seen) {
        this.seen = seen;
    }
}
```

logs [logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArPTw.png)

Debugger datasnapshot value of message [datasnapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq8SG.png)

Firebase db structure [DB Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDjkL.png)

Comment: So basically you are saying that this line of code `views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_message, msg);` doesn't work?

Comment: yes, for some reason I can put the dataSnapshot into a Messages object and call getmessage on it but when I views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_message, msg) it doesnt work nor if I try to Log the message "msg" to the Logs.....No idea why, thanks for a response.Please help.

Comment: Please also add your model class code.

Comment: Added it Thanks Alex

Comment: But if you use `Log.d("TAG", messages.getMessage());` instead of `Log.i("Views", "views");`, does it log the correct message?

Comment: Do you need the whole logcat I've uploaded a photo

Comment: It's a straightforward message. So you are trying to get an object of `Messages class but` `dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class)` returns `null`, that's the problem, right?

Comment: I dunno this is the debugged datasnapshot which shows the value "who" which was the last message received. So don't see how its null...confused please see image i added

Comment: So you get the NPE at which line of code? Not on this `Log.d("TAG", messages.getMessage());`?

Comment: Sorry I was confused it is on that line Log.d("TAG", messages.getMessage());

Comment: Yes, this is whar I was talking about. The single object that can be `null` is `messages`. So make sure is not `null` by verifying the reference on which you are quering.

Comment: How do i verify its not null an if clause? if so how do i denull it Alex excuse my idiot antics

Comment: Check for nullity but this is not how to solve the issue, you need to verify the reference on which you are quering to be sure it return the objects that you are looking for.

Comment: It is null,  you're right!! why isn't it returning the string that the datasnapshot is retrieving?

Comment: Please add your database structure, to see it more clearly.

Comment: I have but the query is working I'm sure because the datasnapshot retrieved the correct message. Still , I've uploaded it.Thanks

Comment: I see now, I'll write you an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments and seeing your database structure, I can tell you that you need to loop through the `msgReceiverId` node to get its children using `getChildren()` method like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("Messages").child(my_Id).child(msgReceiverId).limitToLast(1);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
            String message = messages.getMessage();
            Log.d("TAG", message.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be the last text message.